# C#: MySQL Connectiostring and SqlCommand didnt accept Keyword Port

Tags: c#, mysql, port

i'm trying to make some statement with this connectionstring but SqlCommand didnt accept Keyword 'Port', my MySql didnt use default port, so i need this to connect. Can someone help me?

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionExterno"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from DOADOR where idDOADOR =" + 2 + "", cnn);
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    lblStatus.Text = "Connection Open !";
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        lbNome.Text = reader["nome"].ToString();
    }
    cnn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Can not open connection !";
}
```

This is connectionstring, i changed info with "XXXX".

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLConnectionExterno" connectionString="Server=XXXXX.com;Port=41890;user id=XXXXX;password=XXXXX;persist security info=True;database=XXXXXX" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

[image: IMG01: This is what happens when i try to start]

Comment: Looking at this line: `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from DOADOR where idDOADOR =" + 2 + "", cnn);`. While okay by itself, it makes me wonder whether you typically use correct parameterized queries or whether you write horribly insecure code. There is no middle ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the MySql Connector and use that library instead of the SqlClient library. You can download the connector [from here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Then, you need to install it, add the `MySql.Data.dll` to your project references and add the appropriate using directives to the top of your source files.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

After this you can use the MySql client classes and the MySqlConnection that understand the Port keyword in the connection string

```
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(......)
....
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(.....)
....
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Thanks man, i already tried this but without using MySqlDataReader, my mistake kkkk.